# How to modify the scope in an event in a service (factory)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I created a factory that creates an audio tag with different audio files played.

What I want to do, is to make a loading gif appears while it load a new audio file, then disappear when it is loaded.

I have a simple html tag for my gif:

```
<img src="loading.gif" ng-show="displaySoundFileLoader"/>
```

with my var displaySoundFileLoader at true or false according to what is called in my controller. (false at loading, then true before calling the audio.loadfile(id))

My factory is:

```
  factory('audio',function ($document) {
    var audioElement = $document[0].createElement('audio'); //we add to the dom, it is independent to the scope like that
    return {
      audioElement: audioElement,
      audioSrc: null,//See hack for Chrome below

      loadfile: function(id) {
          this.audioSrc = 'http://mysupersoundlibrary.com/sound.php?id='+id;
          this.play();//and we play it
      },
      play: function() {
          audioElement.src = this.audioSrc;//Small hack because bug in Chrome... See for more info: https://mkswap.net/m/blog/How+to+use+HTML+5+%26lt%3Baudio%26gt%3B+with+JavaScript
          audioElement.play();
      }

    };
  });
```

Like this I can just load & play a sound with a button, then re-play it as much as we want (I don't want to display the player)

The problem is, when I try to do this:

```
audio.audioElement.oncanplaythrough = function () {
    $scope.displaySoundFileLoader = false;
    alert('test');
};
```

I tried with the scope in parameter, I tried many things, it doesn't work (the alert test works). How can I modify the scope in an event of a factory object?

Comment: I think you need `$scope.$apply(function () { $scope.displaySoundFileLoader = false; });`. You are setting an event handler for something outside of Angular, and Angular won't know to update the view, even though you're changing the scope. The `$scope.$apply` will handle that

Comment: best way will be to create a directive for this loader and then watch the displaySoundFileLoader and whenever it's changed you do an apply.  Also you can plug in and event listener as well.

Comment: Both the suggestions are correct. To make your code work, use `$scope.apply` to wrap the assignment. This will tell Angular to run the digest loop. The second answer is correct because that's how you should have done this in the first place instead of using factory.

Comment: Thank you @Ian , it works! Don't hesitate to post as an answer to make me valid it. For z.a. and vaidik , I will try to explore more about the directive part this afternoon, thank you for your help, I am doing this project to train myself to Angular and I am looking a lot how to use the "right way"!